# Keeping console.log() line numbers in a wrapper function in TypeScript / Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, console.log

I am try to make a logging service for my TypeScript / Angular 2 App. Unfortunately if i call console.log the line number is wrong. Even if i try to `return console.log()`.

Here is my code:

***LoggerService.ts***

```
export class LoggerService {    
  log(message) {
    // Server-side logging
    // [...]
    if (clientSideLogging) return console.log(message);
  }
}
```

***SomewhereElse.ts***

```
this.logger.log('hello world');
```

-> Shows line number of LoggerService.ts instead of source

Comment: is it a typescript compile time error?

Answer (score 9):

You could use the [`.bind()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to bind `window.console` to your custom log method and then return the function so that the code is executed within the original scope when it is called.

In doing so, the line number will be preserved when calling the logger service's `log` method:

```
class LoggerService {
  public log = console.log.bind(window.console);
}

// ...or annotated:
class LoggerService {
  public log: (message) => void = console.log.bind(window.console);
}
```

Then if you want to add in your conditional statement:

```
class LoggerService {
  public log = clientSideLogging ? console.log.bind(window.console) : () => {};
}
```

Here is [an example](https://jsfiddle.net/9pu2eu6u/) with the compiled TypeScript code.

---

Aside from the one-liner solutions mentioned above, if you want to implement additional logic inside of the `log` method, then you could utilize a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) which will return and call the `console.log` function that is bound to `window.console`.

```
class LoggerService {
  public get log (): Function {
    // Implemnt server-side logging

    return console.log.bind(window.console);
  }
}
```

As you can tell, it is important for the `console.log` function to be returned since it will not preserve the line numbers when it is called directly within another scope.

Then if you want to add in your conditional statement:

```
class LoggerService {
  public get log (): Function {
    const log = console.log.bind(window.console);

    // Implemnt server-side logging

    return clientSideLogging ? log : () => {};
  }
}
```

Here is [an example](https://jsfiddle.net/o83k63m4/) with the compiled TypeScript code.

Comment: what about the server side logging and other actions that should be performed on logger.log(msg)?

Comment: @JoshCrozier Is there a way to access the arguments sent to the log(). I want to send them to server.

Comment: Finally a solution that WORKS!! this should be starred!

Comment: @Granga's comment is the big deal breaker with this solution. Binding to console.log is great, but not being able to do anything else with the message input means it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Tawm Back when I had this problem, I found out that we can still use `bind` but for log to bring us back to the wanted line of code, we have to use another pair of brackets. You can see an example [here](https://github.com/Granga/ts-class-logger). My requirement was to be able to send log parameters to server when an error was logged on client.

Comment: @Granga Thank you for that! Very interesting solution. Do you know what the `function()()` syntax is called? If possible, I'd prefer to not need that additional () present for ease of use for other developers on my program.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.trace()` instead of `.log()`.

`this.logger.trace('hello world');`

This will give you a stack trace to the original line number.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/trace